# Tricky determinant , I seem to be close to computing it

Tags: determinant

Compute 
$\begin{vmatrix}
1+x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & ... & x_n \\ 
x_1 & 1+x_2 & x_3 & ... & x_n\\
. &.&.&&. \\
. &.&.&&. \\
. &.&.&&. \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & ... & 1+x_n 
\\
\end{vmatrix}\\ $.
I tried to subtract the kth row from the (k-1)th,but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 2):

if you subtract off $I,$ you have a rank one matrix with eigenvalues $$ (0,0,0,\ldots,0, x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)  $$
Add back the $I$ each eigenvalue increases by 1